# RxJava2: How to improve parallel data downloading and caching?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am fighting my way through RxJava2. I'm wondering if my solution is acceptable or are there any ways to improve it.

**Usecase**

1. User presses update data button
2. A dialog is shown - please wait
3. Several backend calls are processed in parallel
4. As soon as any of these finishes - data are saved in local database
5. After all requests are finished (backend call and persisting) the dialog should be dismissed

**Current solution**

I have several `Completables` looking like this:

```
Completable organisationUnitCompletable = backendService.getOrganisationUnits()
    .doOnNext(data -> organisationUnitDao.saveInTx(data))
    .ignoreElements()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

Completable locationCompletable = backendService.getLocations()
    .doOnNext(data -> locationDao.saveInTx(data))
    .ignoreElements()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

Completable prioritiesCompletable = backendService.getPriorities()
    .doOnNext(data -> priorityDao.saveInTx(data))
    .ignoreElements()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

I pack them into one by adding to a list and using `merge` operator:

```
List<Completable> compatibles = new ArrayList<>();
compatibles.add(organisationUnitCompletable);
compatibles.add(locationCompletable);
compatibles.add(prioritiesCompletable);

Completable.merge(compatibles)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(() -> {
     progressDialog.dismiss();
});
```

**Possible improvements**

Ok so this works as intended. But there are things I'm not so happy about.

Do I really have to add the `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to each Completable? It doesn't work in parallel without it, but maybe there is a better way to do this?

All completables have these lines.

```
    .ignoreElements()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Is there a way to extract it into one method? I've tried something like this:

```
private <T> Completable prepareCompletable(Function<Void, Observable<List<T>>> source, AbstractDao<T, Long> dao) {

    Completable orderTypeCompletable = source
            .doOnNext(data -> dao.saveInTx(data))
            .ignoreElements()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

where I would just put the Observable and DAO into. Of course it doesn't compile. It seems that it requires far more knowledge about generics than I already have.

Sorry for the long question, it's hard to explain the whole usecase in just few words.

Comment: nice and clear question. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really have to add the subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) to each Completable?

Yes, but you don't need it after `Completable.merge()`.

> Is there a way to extract it into one method?

```
public static <T> Function<Flowable<T>, Completable> applyIgnore() {
    return f -> f.ignoreElements().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}

Completable locationCompletable = backendService.getLocations()
.doOnNext(data -> locationDao.saveInTx(data))
.to(applyIgnore());
```